# Run code if not running from an include

Tags: php

page1.php:

```
include 'page2.php';
echo $info;
```

page2.php:

```
$info = "some info";
if(!included){
  echo 'Why are you on this page?';
}
```

The goal of `if(!included){` is to determine if `page2.php` was loaded via `include` in `page1.php`, or if the user requested the page directly. There is no function in the docs that returns such a value. How can I create such a function?

Comment: I want this, I want that? What?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Do the want, what dance

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Am bad at dancing :p

Comment: @Mooseman It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I rewrote my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have basically two options:

a) Check with `debug_backtrace` if you're being included

```
$bt = end(debug_backtrace()); // supposing that you don't include in functions / from other included files etc...
if (!empty($bt) && in_array($bt["function"], array("include", "include_once", "require", "require_once"))) {
    // you're being included!
}
```

b) Define some constant, variable etc. in page1.php and check in page2.php if it exists (`defined` or `isset`)

Comment: Is debug_backtrace still as expensive as I remember it? It would be a good catch-all solution, but I'm curious.

Comment: It is expensive. But I've proposed you a second solution with constants/variables which you can use if you don't need such a slow catch-all function.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (__FILE__ == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) {
   echo "wild and free!";
}
```

Comment: No... WRONG! `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` doesn't contain the full path, only the directory structure apparent in the URL while `__FILE__` contains the full path from the file system root on.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing/agreeing with bwoebi, you can make a define.

In page1.php:

```
define("PAGE1_NOT_USER", true);
```

In page2.php, for the code you only want to run on the user request:

```
if(!defined("PAGE1_NOT_USER"))
{
    <code here>
}
```

My PHP is rusty, but that should do the trick. The debug option covers all bases: Mine just covers this (and anywhere else you might use the define).